# How shift record after delete a record in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a question: I have a table that it has columns `id,name,rownumber`. `rownumber` is `int` and it has `1,2,3,4,..` numbers.

When I want to insert in table I get `max(rownumber)` and insert `max(rownumber)+1` for new row. But I want to when delete a row, for example when delete a row that rownumber is 3, I want to refresh `rownumber` and shift `rownumber`.

How can I do it? please help me.
thanks.

Comment: This is a **REALLY REALLY B-A-A-A-A-D** idea ... don't do it! If you **really** need row numbers - let SQL Server compute them for you, when you really need them - most of time, you probably **don't** need them anyway... Also: use `max(rownumber)+1` for your new ID is also very much in danger of causing duplicates in a system with a certain amount of concurrent users.... **don't do it!!** use the built-in functionality that SQL Server has to offer! That's much easier and much safer, too

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks, that inspired me to highlight the important parts in my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have 10 or perhaps 100 records and performance doesn't matter that much, you could use something like:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var query = ctx.Entities
        .Where(e => e.RowNumber > entityToDelete.RowNumber)
        .OrderBy(e => e.RowNumber);

    foreach (var entity in query)
        entity.RowNumber -= 1;

    ctx.DeleteObject(entityToDelete);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you have thousands of records and performance is important the code above is a **REALLY REALLY B-A-A-A-A-D** idea. A better solution would be a Stored Procedure to avoid loading so many data into memory and sending so many UPDATE commands (for every changed record) to the DB. Much better would be to **AVOID THIS RENUMBERING IN THE FIRST PLACE** (if it's not absolutely necessary) because you have to change to lot of other records obviously, only because you delete one single record.

**Edit** Highlighted the important part of the answer in **bold**.

Comment: +1 absolutely. With thousands or even hundreds of thousands of rows, you'd be renumbering the whole stuff all the time and wasting your time doing so.....

Answer (score 0):

Slauma covered most of the downsides of doing this. Imagine if you would add relations to this table, for each relation you would have to change the other tables reference according to the new rownumbers. This could be very dangerous. Whats the problem with leaving it as it is?